# how to use jr:table in jrxml with PDFReporter on Android

Tags: android, pdf, jasper-reports, report

I'm using PDFReporter for Android to export my reports to pdf files but I have got stuck with element jr:table in jrxml. PDFReporter gives me an exception telling that there is no method DatasetRun on object ComponenElement.
Is there anyone have generated pdf reports using PDFReporter on Android with a table? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What is *PDFReporter*?

Comment: @AlexK: That's a report library base on JasperReport, it supports Android and iOS. Please go to this link http://www.pdfreporting.com/ for more information.